# RxJS - change onClicks(JS) to myEvents(RxJS)

Tags: javascript, html, rxjs

I'm pretty much brand new to RxJS and I need to change my `onClick`s to `myEvent`s, I'm having a problem where I cannot interact with buttons that are created in the JS since they are not created in the HTML. The project is a simple note-taking app. TIA!
stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w9lthb?file=index.html

```
fromEvent(button, "click").subscribe(() => {
    i++;
    j++;
    let NotesArea = document.getElementById("NoteArea").value;
    let Colour = document.getElementById("colours").value;
    NotesArray.push(NotesArea);

    document.getElementById("NotesCollection").innerHTML += ("<div id=\"Div"+ i +"\" > <button id=\""+ i +"\">Edit Note</button> <button id=\""+ i +"\">Delete Note</button><div id = \"Note"+ i +"\" > <p>" + NotesArea + "</p> </div></div>");
    document.getElementById(("Note"+i)).style.backgroundColor = Colour;

    const editbutton = document.getElementById(i);
    const deletebutton = document.getElementById(i);
})

fromEvent(editbutton, "click").subscribe(() => {
    j = id;
    document.getElementById("Note"+j).innerHTML += ("<textarea id=\"EditArea\" name=\"EditArea\" rows=\"3\" cols=\"30\"> </textarea> <button onclick=\"SubmitEdit(EditArea, i)\">Submit edit</button>");
    const submitbutton = document.getElementById(i);
})

fromEvent(submitbutton, "click").subscribe(() => {
    let varofAdd = val.value;
    NotesArray[i] = varofAdd;
    document.getElementById("Note"+j).innerHTML = ("<div id = \"Note"+ i +"\" > <p>" + varofAdd + "</p> </div>");
})

fromEvent(deletebutton, "click").subscribe(() => {
    let DivNum = id;
    console.log(DivNum);
    document.getElementById("Div" + DivNum).innerHTML = " ";
})
```

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/) sample of the above. Will be easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

RxJS declaring everything in variables on start of your application. If you change your source listener dynamically, - you should recreate the stream.

For example:

```
const editbutton = new BehaviorSubject(yourInitHTMLButtonOrNull);

editbutton.pipe(switchMap(buttonElement => fromEvent(buttonElement, "click"))).subscribe(() => {...});
```

Same for other you dynamic buttons. Also you should change this buttons as a `Subject` values:

```
fromEvent(button, "click").subscribe(() => {
    i++;
    j++;
    ...

    editbutton.next(document.getElementById(i));
    deletebutton.next(document.getElementById(i));
})
```